# Safari on iPhone 5 not displaying slider on website

Tags: html, css, safari, slider, iphone-5

A friend of mine has asked me to take a look at her website - http://www.nails-more.co.uk

The slider right at the top of the homepage isn't showing on Safari on the iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.4. This is where it gets strange. It works fine on my iPhone, but not my friend's - which is exactly the same with the same settings etc. Have tried the usual clearing history, rebooting etc.

This is a comparison of how it works on one device but not the other identical one -

[image]

It seems to work perfectly in all other browsers. Have tried a Safari iPhone simulator online and that works fine (found the link on here somewhere).

Does anyone know what the issue can be?

Comment: You have checked that Javascript is turned on, right? That'd be the most likely cause...

Answer (score 0):

Bit hard to tell from screenshots but I can replicate what you're describing by disabling Javascript (Settings > Safari > Javascript OFF).